# How to add/remove disabled in a default wordpress comments form

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, button, submit

I am basically designing a spam filter for my wordpress blog. So I created an extra field "Void" which when filled should disable the submit button. For now void is of course visible later I will hide it. The problem is I am unable to introduce my custom jQuery code I've tried so hard. I used:

```
function collectiveray_theme_scripts_function() {
  wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/antispam.js', array ( 'jquery' ), 3.1, true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','collectiveray_theme_scripts_function');
```

But it didn't seem to work. Then I added this code:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit').prop('disabled',true);
    $('#void').keyup(function(){
        $('.submit').prop('disabled', this.value == "" ? true : false);     
    })
    }); 
</script>
```

To header.php and footer.php but it seems like it is not targeting anything at all.
Here is a link to the website: [Link](https://sambadiary.com/?p=3625)

Comment: Have you imported `JQuery`??

Comment: The theme js already has a bundle.min.js file so I assume the site loads jQuery

Comment: Assuming is not definitive. Load the page and check to see if there is a `JQuery` file in the content. Also, check the console window for errors. You could also check in the console window via: `typeof jQuery == 'undefined'`

Comment: Should I simply hook the jquery library in header.php? jquery-migrate exists though

Comment: Yes, you should place the JQuery import inside the header if it doesn't already get loaded into your page. Also, it should be loaded before the jquery-migrate.